# Microcontroller stm8 disassembly

Tags: disassembly, stm8

Is it possible to disassemble hex **stm8** firmware?

Comment: File firmware .hex - http://rgho.st/download/7vsCNsnB8/2416d20a3037ed3f1c515f6c29af79f9c2304d0e/oldtermo.hex

Answer (score 3):

This IDA Pro 6.6 plugin seems to work. https://github.com/derbroti/Stm8Ida

Assuming you're on Windows:

1. Open the VS2013 solution and build using IDA 6.6 SDK headers and libs. You will need to add idasdk66\include and idasdk66\module to the list of includes and idasdk66\lib\x86_win_vc_32 to the list of library locations in your project file.
2. Then copy the output, st8.w32 to: C:\Program Files (x86)\IDA 6.6\procs

Answer (score 2):

Your file consist of two sections 8000-87FFh and 8800-BFFFh. Apparently first is bootloader, second is main programm. 
You can disassemble they separately.

I have tried to do the following:

1. Just cut and save first section to one file, and second to another.
2. Disassemble each file with [naked_asm](https://github.com/mikeakohn/naken_asm): `naken_util.exe -disasm -stm8 ./fw.hex > ./fw.asm`
3. As result I have got two asm files: [main.asm](http://rgho.st/8P7MldyhK) and [boot.asm](http://rgho.st/8X6ZT4MWd)

Boot file begin with common IRQ table. Main file destine all IRQs to 886Bh where seems begin `main()` function, and the first instruction is `asm("sim")` that disable all IRQs.

Further you can use some more complex programm such as [IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/) and decomplie they to source if you need.